# magento : some htaccess redirection doesn't work

Tags: apache, .htaccess, magento, mod-rewrite, seo

With magento 1.7 FR, I have some redirection rules in htaccess but not all are working and I can't find why :

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on

# This is working
Redirect 301 /blog/conseils-literie/literie-et-matelas-pirelli.html http://example.com/produits/literie.html
Redirect permanent /catalogues/ http://example.com/

# This is not working !
Redirect 301 /produits.html?marque=32 http://example.com/32/bultex.html
# I replaced it with this but no way !
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com/produits.html?marque=32
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/32/bultex.html$1 [R=301,L]
```

I'm sure there is no URL redirection set from the backend !

Comment: Is that your whole .htaccess file? Are you sure you don't have rewrite or redirect rules in, for example, the httpd.conf file?

Comment: I found this simulator : http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/. I tired with these rules :  RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^marque=32$   \n   RewriteRule ^produits.html /32/bultex.html [NC,R,L] ... The simulator says it's ok but the rules are not working in real server !!

Comment: Added a bounty which hopefully drive enough attention to the thread that you get an answer. Please try the examples you get and also **accept** the answer that works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is working fine on my server :

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /produits\.html\?marque=([^&\s]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1/bultex.html? [NE,NC,R,L]
```

Remove or comment out the redirect line in your .htaccess and put this rule there. Don't remove the **?** from the end of the target url otherwise the query string "?marque=32" will be appended to it and the url will look like :

```
/32/bultex.html?marque=32
```